# Run DialogFlow Queries on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, dialogflow-es

I am using dialog flow (api.ai). The user will input a Linux Command, How do I automatically extract that and then run it on a Linux machine.

I have tried sending dialog flow queries to a database, then a GDoc reads that database and adds the command on the document. Then Linux reads from the GDoc and runs the command. However, this isn't really efficient and doesn't really work that well.

Any ideas on how to do this?

--Edit

Well, the user says normal statements, then keywords from those statements are seen and the appropriate Linux command needs to be sent.

Example: Show Spain on Linux PC

It sees keyword Spain and sends a command to Linux to send Spain.
*I just don't know how to connect up dialog flow to Linux to send those commands*

Comment: if user is sending Linux commands, what do you need DialogFlow for? you can directly get the command and run it on Linux machine.

Comment: concur with @sid8491. Unless you want the user to make broad statements in a human language and you're trying to execute them. Can you update your question to provide some examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay, I just edited it with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the big picture you will be running a program on your machine on which user will write something.

When user sends that text, it will trigger DialogFlow api using [SDK's](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks) provided by Dialogflow using Language of your choice.

You will recieve a response from DialogFlow and then trigger Terminal along with the command.